# How to print these specific elements of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, integer

I am practicing how to print specific elements of the array.
The output should be
Elements in the array:

```
-5 -3 -1 1 3 5 7 9 
-2 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 
4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 
7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21
```

fc
I have tried different times but the output is still not the exactly the same. Thank you

```
System.out.println("Elements in the array: "); 
int[][] intArr = new int[5][8];
for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < intArr[i].length; j++){
        intArr[i][j] = i * 3 + j*2 - 5;
            
        if(j == 0){                                   
            System.out.println(intArr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print(intArr[i][j]);
        
    }
}
```

Elements in the array:
-5 -3 -1 1 3 5 7 9
-2 0 2 4 6 8 10 12
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18
7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21

Comment: Why have an array in the first place, if you are printing immediately after putting the element into the array?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently missing an `else`, but an easier solution exists; just print a newline after each row (that is after the inner loop finishes). Like,

```
System.out.println("Elements in the array: ");
int[][] intArr = new int[5][8];
for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < intArr[i].length; j++) {
        intArr[i][j] = i * 3 + j * 2 - 5;
        System.out.printf("%d ", intArr[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
Elements in the array: 
-5 -3 -1 1 3 5 7 9 
-2 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 
4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 
7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21
```

Comment: To align the array elements and get a cleaner output, just change it to `"%2d "`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use an array.  You can add it back if it is required.  But here is one way using no arrays and [System.out.printf()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

```
System.out.println("Generated Elements: "); 
int columns = 8;
int rows = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        System.out.printf("%2d ", i * 3 + j*2 - 5);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
Generated Elements: 
-5 -3 -1  1  3  5  7  9 
-2  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 
 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 
 4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 
 7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21
```